# How to add option menus when creating a set of data in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi Im quite new to Tkinter and this site.

In tkinter I want to be able to add an option menu showing the list of items and suppliers a user can choose to make an order but I have no clue as to how to get the option menu to follow the same command as with the date price and quantity

Here is my code so far for this frame: (I can provide other data if needed)

```
 # Frame 5 - Add Order - window that allows the user to make an order using several entry widgets
    def create_Order_Var():
        f5.tkraise()
        # Data headings
        Label(f5, text="Date 'dd/mm/yy'",bg="#E5E5E5", anchor="w").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
        Label(f5, text="Price",bg="#E5E5E5", anchor="w").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E+W)
        Label(f5, text="Quantity",bg="#E5E5E5", anchor="w").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=E+W)
        Label(f5, text="Item ID",bg="#E5E5E5", anchor="w").grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=E+W)
        Label(f5, text="Supplier ID",bg="#E5E5E5", anchor="w").grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=E+W)

        # Setting variables to approriate types
        newDate = StringVar()
        newPrice = DoubleVar() 
        newQuantity = DoubleVar()
        newItemID = IntVar() 
        newSupplierID = IntVar()

        #Item Option Menu
        variable = StringVar(f5)
        variable.set("Select Item") # default value

        items = get_all_inventory()
        items_formatted = []
        for item in items:
            items_formatted.append(item[0])
        print(items_formatted)
        # Establishing option menu widget
        optionbox = OptionMenu(f5, variable, *items_formatted)

        #Supplier Option Menu
        variable2 = StringVar(f5)
        variable2.set("Select Supplier") # default value

        suppliers = get_all_suppliers()
        suppliers_formatted = []
        for supplier in suppliers:
            suppliers_formatted.append(supplier[0])
        print(suppliers_formatted)
        # Establishing option menu widget
        optionbox2 = OptionMenu(f5, variable2, *suppliers_formatted)

        # Establishing entry widgets
        entry_Date = Entry(f5,textvariable=newDate).grid(row=1,column=1)
        entry_Price = Entry(f5,textvariable=newPrice).grid(row=2,column=1)
        entry_Quantity = Entry(f5,textvariable=newQuantity).grid(row=3,column=1)
        entry_ItemID = optionbox.grid(row=4,column=1)
        entry_SupplierID = optionbox2.grid(row=5,column=1)

        def add_Order():              

            try:
                date = newDate.get()
                price = newPrice.get()
                quantity = newQuantity.get()
                itemID = newItemID.get()
                supplierID = newSupplierID.get()                    
                # Stops invalid data by disallowing fields with the wrong data type
                float(price) 
                int(quantity)
                int(itemID)
                int(supplierID)
                # Calling of create order query
                create_order(date,price,quantity,itemID,supplierID)
                print("You have added: {0},{1},{2},{3},{4}".format(date,price,quantity,itemID,supplierID))
                # After an order has been place the window switches to the check order frame for the user to check that their order was made
                check_Order()
            except:
                # Error message when invalid data is entered
                print("Invalid Data. Price must be a number above zero. Quantity must be an integer above zero")

        Button(f5,text = "Create Order",command = add_Order).grid(row = 6, column = 2, padx = 10)
```

Comment: do you get error message ? always add FULL error message (Traceback) in question.

Comment: No I don't get any error message because the Item and Supplier Option menus don't have any command

Comment: you have menu selection in `variable.get()` and you have to use it with `items` to find `date` and `price`. It could be easier if you had dictionary instead of list.

Answer (score 0):

You have selected option in `variable.get()` and now you have to use it to find other information in `items` list. It could be easier if you had dictionary instead of list.

Example with list

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def on_button():

    # - list -

    # selected option
    sel_list = select_list.get()
    print('list - key:', sel_list)

    # find on list
    keys_list = [x[0] for x in items_list]

    if sel_list in keys_list:
        idx = keys_list.index(sel_list)
        item_list = items_list[idx]
    else:
        item_list =  None

    print('list - item:', item_list)

    print('---')

# --- data ---

# - list -

# list with items
items_list = [
    ['Item A', 'Today', 'Hello'],
    ['Item B', 'Tomorrow', 'World']
]

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

# - list -

# variable for selected item
select_list = tk.StringVar()
select_list.set("Select Item")

# use list first column as options
keys_list = [x[0] for x in items_list]

op_list = tk.OptionMenu(root, select_list, *keys_list)
op_list.pack()

# -

b = tk.Button(root, text='OK', command=on_button)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Example with dictionary

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def on_button():

    # - dictionary -

    # selected option
    sel_dict = select_dict.get()
    print('dict - key:', sel_dict)

    # find in dictionary
    if sel_dict in items_dict:
        item_dict = items_dict[sel_dict]
    else:
        item_dict = None

    print('dict - item:', item_dict)

    print('---')

# --- data ---

# - dictionary -

# dictionary with items
items_dict = {
    'Item A': ['Today', 'Hello'],
    'Item B': ['Tomorrow', 'World']
}

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

# - dictionary -

# variable for selected item
select_dict = tk.StringVar()
select_dict.set("Select Item")

# use dictionary keys as options
# (dictionary doesn't have to keep order so I sort it)
keys_dict = sorted(items_dict)

op_dict = tk.OptionMenu(root, select_dict, *keys_dict)
op_dict.pack()

# -

b = tk.Button(root, text='OK', command=on_button)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```